# Simple Android Room Query returns nothing

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Entity:

```
@Entity
data class Recipe(
    @NotNull
    var name: String,
...
```

DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT name FROM Recipe" )
fun getRecipesNames():List<String>
```

Useage:

```
    val db = Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, RDB::class.java, "db").build()
    val rdao = db.RecipeDAO()
    val rcps = rdao.getRecipesNames()
```

I've confirmed that the data exists in the database and can get the names if I request individual items, but not if I request all of the names. There is no error, only an empty list.

Comment: Can you show us the Query that is actually working?

Comment: `@Query("SELECT * FROM Recipe where name = :name")
  
  fun getRecipe(name:String):Recipe`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Query("Select * FROM Recipe")
fun getRecipes(): List<Recipe>
```

I don't know what's wrong with your code. Know me if this works.